# Pass double to Viewcontroller then to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Full Code

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerImage : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *datum;
    IBOutlet UILabel *debug;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) double thicknessValue1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double capWidthValue1;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [datum setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];

    NSString *value =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", self.thicknessValue1];

    debug.text = value;

    draw2D *myView = [[draw2D alloc]initWithThickness: self.thicknessValue1 andCapWidth: self.capWidthValue1];

    NSLog(@"First Logs");
    NSLog(@"%f",myView.thicknessValue2);
    NSLog(@"%f",myView.capWidthValue2);
    NSLog(@"END FIRST LOGS");
}
```

draw2D.h
    #import

```
@interface draw2D : UIView 

- (id)initWithThickness:(double)thickness andCapWidth:(double)capWith;


@property (nonatomic, assign) double thicknessValue2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double capWidthValue2;

@end
```

draw2D.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface draw2D : UIView 

- (id)initWithThickness:(double)thickness andCapWidth:(double)capWith
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        thicknessValue2 = self.thicknessValue2;
        capWidthValue2 = self.capWidthValue2;
        NSLog(@"Second Logs");
        NSLog(@"%f",thicknessValue2);
        NSLog(@"%f",capWidthValue2);
        NSLog(@"END Second LOGS");
    }
    return self;
}



@end
```

I have provided you with my full code from the second view controller as well as the UIView, I hope you can see where I am going wrong. Or explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So the problem is that in drawRect:(CGRect)rect the value you read from self.thicknessValue2 and self.capWidthValue2; is 0 ? In which method are you allocating draw2d * myView ?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I read @Thedude 's comment and think I missed something. `[[draw2D alloc]init];` where are you setting the frame ?  `drawRect` won't get called if it has no `CGRect`

Comment: Added the full draw2d.m, my issue isn't that the drawRect doesn't get called as the images work for me, except the variables that are carried over are detrimental to what the drawRect will draw.

Comment: @DanielWatson In which method are you: `draw2D *myView = [[draw2D alloc]init];`

Comment: That is in the `- (void) viewDidLoad` of the second viewcontroller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207230/objective-c-pass-a-value-from-uiviewcontroller-to-uiview-i-keep-getting-null This guy appears to have had a similar problem to me, yet he doesn't explain his answer very well. If this helps to a solution?

Comment: You create the view but where do you put it on the screen?

Comment: @Phillip Mills I'm not too sure what you mean by your question?

Comment: @DanielWatson try creating the custom `init` anyway, `drawRect` gets called whenever `needsDisplay` is set or when you use `[ addSubview:]`. Without the complete code we don't know where these are being called. Putting a few `NSLogs` throughtout your code will easily tell if the values are being passed in before they are getting called or not but aside from that Its bad practise to leave required values like these outside the init function anyway

Comment: Adding the NSLogs,
        NSLog(@"Second Logs");
        NSLog(@"%f",self.thicknessValue2);
        NSLog(@"%f",self.capWidthValue2);
        NSLog(@"END Second LOGS"); at the -viewdidload, then a second set in the drawRect shows that they are being called in the correct order, except the values are 0.

Comment: @DanielWatson I meant more adding a log to the start of the `drawRect:` and one on the line before you set the values to the view instance `myView`, to see which is being called first

Comment: @DanielWatson please use "@<username>" to notify me of your comments, I have to keep checking back to see did you post something

Comment: @Simon McLoughlin , I apologise for that, I wasn't aware that's how it worked. I'm struggling to interpret your comment, 1. how do I create the custom init? - (id)initWithThickNessValue2(double)thicknessValue2? not too sure on the addSubview or needsDisplay, I've tried adding a few NSLogs to the viewcontroller.m and the draw2D.m and they're called in the correct order if it's inside the drawRect, but the values from the viewcontroller are correct but draw2D are 0.000

Comment: @DanielWatson too long for a comment so I created another answer

Comment: Make sure that you're creating the object before you assign values to it, and that you only create the object once.

Comment: Here's a reference you should read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html  Look, in particular, at the section called "Creating and Managing a View Hierarchy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer as the previous is already too long.

Dude I physically can not do any more than this, it is not complex at all. I'm sorry but not finding info online about creating an object is just not true, its quite literally everywhere. Where did I learn it?

2 things to note.

1. Naming convention says classes start with a capital e.g. `draw2d` needs to be `Draw2d`
2. You shouldn't be naming variables xxx1, xxx2 etc. If they are the same thing, name them the same thing. It doesn't matter if they are different classes.

**Code:**

In viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Before init");
    Draw2d *myView = [[Draw2d alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320) thickness:15.0 capwidth:17.5];
    NSLog(@"After init");
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    NSLog(@"After placing on superview at x= 0, y = 0, width = 320, height = 320");
}
```

Draw2d.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Draw2d : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) double thickness;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double capWidth;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame thickness:(double)thickness capwidth:(double)capWidth;

@end
```

Draw2d.m

```
#import "Draw2d.h"

@implementation Draw2d

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame thickness:(double)thickness capwidth:(double)capWidth
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        // Left side is property in .h
        // right side is the parameters passed into method
        self.thickness = thickness;
        self.capWidth = capWidth;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Passed in thickness: %f", self.thickness);
    NSLog(@"Passed in capWidth: %f", self.capWidth);
}


@end
```

Console:

```
2014-04-16 09:23:23.613 Before init
2014-04-16 09:23:23.613 After init
2014-04-16 09:23:23.613 After placing on superview at x= 0, y = 0, width = 320, height = 320
2014-04-16 09:23:23.615 Passed in thickness: 15.000000
2014-04-16 09:23:23.616 Passed in capWidth: 17.500000
```

Comment: Thank you so much again for your continuos help, the code you've provided me with works completely now. Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the full flow of your code and based on the fact I see no issue with your setters (unless your modifying the data somewhere else). I suspect the issue is you are trying to call the double values before they have been passed in, but I can't be sure on that.

When you are creating something custom that requires values, it is best practise to have these passed in with the `init` method so you have all the values you need in the custom code and so you don't forget anything each time you create one.

As such you need to create your own `init` method like:

```
- (id)initWithThickness:(double)thickness andCapWidth:(double)capWith
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.thickness = thickness;
        self.capWidth = capWidth;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then call you code like this:

```
draw2D *myView = [[draw2D alloc]initWithThickness: self.thicknessValue1 andCapWidth: self.capWidthValue1];
```

Re: my other comment. `drawRect:` will be called when you (or iOS) calls `[<customView> setNeedsDisplay]` or you call `[view addSubview: <customView>]`. I haven't seen either be used in your code so I'm not sure where or how you are doing any of this. But either way doing this outside a custom `init` would be bad practise.

If this doesn't work please edit your answer to contain the full code as to where and how you create / add this view to the screen.

**EDIT**

Ok as it stands basically your code is doing nothing.

1 . In your `viewDidLoad` you are calling this:

```
draw2D *myView = [[draw2D alloc]initWithThickness: self.thicknessValue1 andCapWidth: self.capWidthValue1];
```

you don't use or do anything with `myView`, this is a pointer to a `draw2D` instance, when the next curly bracket in `viewDidload` is reached, this will disappear without doing anything because its not used anywhere. This is not a transition form PHP to objective-c issue. This is fundamental object oriented programming stuff. As soon as it goes out of scope its gone. Same with an int, if you create an int here and try to call it in `viewDidAppear` you can't because its out of scope, why is UI any different, you haven't asked to draw it to the screen, so therefore it disappears.

2 . Your custom `init` method makes no sense.

```
- (id)initWithThickness:(double)thickness andCapWidth:(double)capWith
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        thicknessValue2 = self.thicknessValue2;
        capWidthValue2 = self.capWidthValue2;
```

`self` is a reference to the object instance, same as `this` in other languages. What you are trying to do here is set `thicknessValue2` to the `draw2D` property `thicknessValue2` (the second one being self). You are ignoring the variable supplied by the method `thickness` and `capWidth`. I have no idea what the hell `thicknessValue2` (without self) is in this code, but basically here you are receiving values form the code where the `init` is called ... and then saying 0 = 0 twice. I clearly gave you code that said `self.thickness = thickness` = `self.<draw2D property name> = <supplied variable from method>`. Probably in your case equal to `self.thicknessValue2 = thickness`. Here you haven't read the code or understood how a method works.

3 . I have no idea what your trying to achieve in your `drawRect`

first of all there is no point in doing this:

```
double thickness = thicknessValue2;
double capWidth = capWidthValue2;
```

Why not just use `thicknessValue2` ??? second of all what the hell is `thicknessValue2` should it not be `self.thicknessValue2` ???

ignoring that, nowhere do you pass in a `CGRect` to your `myView` meaning your view has no size or position, and inside your `drawRect` you are not using the supplied rect (which should be 0 because you didn't give one), therefore I have no idea how you think your drawing is inside the view?

If you don't understand some of the more simple concepts I'm not sure why your going down the very complex route of creating a custom `UIView` using a graphics context. This is not a simple case of in PHP you only have to "include a file". You are ignoring the simple aspects of creating `UIViews` and `UIImageViews` and going down the very advanced road of drawing custom UI elements by hand ... of course its not as simple as including a file, are you mad ?

I don't want this to come out the wrong way but I don't have the time to help you with this level of unfamiliarity with objective c. I don't think you understand object oriented code properly based on how your creating instances and using instance methods, there is nothing objective c specific here what so ever, other than the methods having a different syntax, the idea of a pointer to an instance is nothing new. I think you need to read a few books and follow some tutorials because as it stands your code makes little to no sense and I think you are trying to jump into the more advanced stuff before doing the very basic.

**EDIT 2:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [datum setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];

    NSString *value =  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", self.thicknessValue1];

    debug.text = value;

    draw2D *myView = [[draw2D alloc]initWithThickness: self.thicknessValue1 andCapWidth: self.capWidthValue1];

    // Now it will not go out of scope, as it will be added to the 
    // viewControllers view property
    [self.view addSubview:myview];

    NSLog(@"First Logs");
    NSLog(@"%f",myView.thicknessValue2);
    NSLog(@"%f",myView.capWidthValue2);
    NSLog(@"END FIRST LOGS");
}
```

Comment: I've provided you with all of my code from the second view controller and the UIView, I hope you can see where I am going wrong

Comment: @DanielWatson ok most worrying is why you are calling this inside `drawRect` - `draw2D *myView = [[draw2D alloc]initWithThickness: self.thicknessValue1 andCapWidth: self.capWidthValue1];`  This seems like almost recursively calling it as it will in turn call `drawRect` again, what are you trying to achieve here?  2. in `ViewController.m` you set the values in the `init` and then overwrite them on the next line. 3. Again nowhere do I see you using `myView` in the `viewController.m`, you create it and then forget about it as the function ends without using it???

Comment: @DanielWatson 4. When you have `NSLogs` make sure it include the console print outs

Comment: Okay I have amended what you said, but now I get all NSLogs returning 0, when you say I am not using the myView, how should I be using it? This is really puzzling to me, I am very sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: @DanielWatson can you edit your questions code then, i'm concerned with what you were trying to do in the `drawRect` I think you have a massive misunderstanding on what that does and how. Re. the `myView`, in your code you create an instance of `draw2D` and call it `myView` ... thats it, you don't add it as a subview, you don't set it as the view of the view controller. You just create it and ignore it, when the `viewDidLoad` is finished the instance gets thrown out because its not used anywhere. Are you new to object oriented programming also ???

Comment: I have been a self taught PHP programmer for some time, and use objects within that. I'm just struggling to understand Objective C. And where in PHP I would just include a file this I have to do all this so I'm not used to it. I have amended the code as requested

Comment: 15 char^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I agree my level of knowledge is far less than what is required for doing what I am doing, but usually I throw myself in at the deep end and figure it all out eventually, then I'm sorted for a similar problem in the future. I think I've just been changing things left right and centre and lost where I am. But I will go through your response and try to get it to work, as the application I am creating requires this. I really didn't think it would be so difficult to pass a value from the ViewController to the UIView,

Comment: and it will draw the image based on the value entered because it is then manipulated to create what I need it to create. I've already set this up and it works.

Comment: @DanielWatson ok well few pointers then. 1. `myView` will probably need to a property of the viewController and then inside the `viewDidLoad` call `[self.view addSubView:myView];`. 2. You need to be passing in a `CGRect` to the view, override `initWithFrame:` and add in parameters for thickness / capWidth rather than just `init`. 3. Inside the `drawRect` you need to be aware of the dimensions of the view (the supplied `rect` parameter). Good luck

Comment: anything I try and add like [self.view addSubView:myView]; results in nothing but an error. I think I'll go watch some UIView tutorials before attempting this again. Thanks I have accepted your answer is it is most likely correct I just can't interpret it.

Comment: @DanielWatson see edit 2. Not sure if you copied my typo or not, auto complete in Xcode should have sorted that out anyway. Its a lowercase v in Subview

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I still cannot get it. Even though my brain appears to be more functional today.. 3 days of no progress, literally all I need to do is make the variables `thickness` and `capWidth` == `self.thicknessValue1` in the viewController. There must surely be a simpler way than this. I cannot find information on it anywhere. Sorry to be a pest.

Comment: @DanielWatson added another answer